# UI Automated Testing For Android

Tags: android, testing, user-interface, apk

Which tools is best for automated UI testing for Android using the apk, i.e without having step down into the code. I tried robotium, but it requires code-level knowledge.

My requirement is to automate the positive flow testing for my app using the apk.

Can anyone suggest some good tools for the same??

Comment: Well there is monkey testing. I tried that with my own app, and it worked OK. There are limitations to automated testing, buy I am sure you are aware of those.

Answer (score 1):

You can test Robotium Recorder, has free trial version

http://robotium.com/